# Stuck on trying to get this program to work. (New to Java, used to python.)

Tags: java, loops

Trying to get this program to work, however, it doesn't want to work.
These are the requirements.
Write a Java program to calculate student’s final course grade. The program should:
(1) Prompt and read user’s input for the student’s name, assignment 1 grade (A1), assignment 2
grade (A2), exam grade (EX), and participation grade (P). User Scanner to read input.
(2) Each grade input should be 0-100 and the final grade should be calculated as follows:
A1*0.25+A2*0.25+EX*0.4+P*0.1
(3) Output the student’s information and the calculated course grade
(4) prompt user whether they want to calculate grade for another student and repeat the
input/output processing
(5) Allow user to exit program without inputting student’s data

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asgn3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * (1) Prompt and read user’s input for the student’s name, assignment
     *  1 grade (A1), assignment 2 grade (A2), exam grade (EX), and 
     * participation grade (P). User Scanner to read input.
     */
    
    /*
     * (2) Each grade input should be 0-100 and the final grade should be 
     * calculated as follows: A1*0.25+A2*0.25+EX*0.4+P*0.1
     */
    
    /*
     * (3) Output the student’s information and the calculated course grade
     */
    
    /*
     * (4) prompt user whether they want to calculate grade for another 
     * student and repeat the input/output processing
     */
    
    /*
     * (5) Allow user to exit program without inputting student’s data
     */
    
    String StudentName;
    String Continue;
    double A1 = 0; double A2 = 0; double Ex = 0; double P = 0; 
    double FinalGrade = 0;
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculation program.");
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter student's data? Yes/No => ");
    Continue = scanner.toString();
    
    if (Continue == "Yes") {
    System.out.println("Enter student's Name => ");
    StudentName = scanner.toString();
    System.out.println("Enter student's grades seperated by space: A1 A2 "
            + "Ex P => ");
    A1 = scanner.nextDouble(); A2 = scanner.nextDouble(); 
    Ex = scanner.nextDouble(); P = scanner.nextDouble();
    
    FinalGrade = A1*0.25+A2*0.25+Ex*0.4+P*0.1;
    
    System.out.println("Student name: " + StudentName);
    System.out.println("The grades are as follows: A1 = " + A1 + " A2 = " 
    + A2 + " Ex = " + Ex + " P = " + P);
    System.out.println("Final course grade = " + FinalGrade);
    
    }
    
    else {
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the grade calculation "
                + "program");
    scanner.close();
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

The issue is I keep getting this result and won't let me advance from there.

From the Console:
"Welcome to the grade calculation program.
Do you want to enter student's data? Yes/No =>
Thank you for using the grade calculation program"

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the value of scanner.toString() ?

Comment: Your second problem: you can't compare Strings in Java like you do

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Java, in a introductory class for it right now.

Comment: When checking if a String is equal to something, in this case an input, I would rather suggest using `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: In your own words, where you have `scanner.toString()`, what do you expect that to do?

Comment: `==` in Java is more like `is` in Python (except for primitive types).

Answer (score 1):

Hello there I think your if condition doesn't satisfy and it goes directly to else condition because of this line

Continue = scanner.toString();

Change it to this

Continue = scanner.nextLine();

If this also doesn't work then
change the variable Scanner name.

Comment: I swapped my .toString() to .next() and it seemed to solve one issue, but came upon a different error now. 0.o